# how can i create primary keys in spark scala automatically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
|Country|       DOB|     app_name|             contact|               email|              friend|                name|               phone|                 UID|
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  India|25/03/1995|        [IMT]|[[India,123,Wrapp...|[romaahire11@gmai...|[Kashmira G, Bhar...|[Roma Ahire, Roma A]|[9028512546, 7276...|059fe797-c296-46d...|
|  India|22/05/1978|[IMT, ozmott]|[[India,595,Wrapp...|[azeem@yahoo.com,...|[Prjakta W, Praja...|[Azeem, Azeem Seikh]|        [9785213564]|454bc185-5de0-427...|
|  India|22/05/1978|[IMT, ozmott]|[[USA,789,Wrapped...|[praj@yahoo.com, ...|[Gouri Abhyankar,...|[Prajakta W, Praj...|        [9785213564]|91897109-9fd2-4f3...|
+-------+----------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------
```

above is my registerTempTable

Comment: please format your question and provide sufficient explanation and expected output

Comment: what do you mean by primary keys?

Comment: means i want unique identifier.. as this data i want to store in hive table

Comment: The scenario is i have a json file..i stored it in registerTempTable as shown above..now i will transfer it into hive table(spark).If another entry comes into the registerTempTable with same email address then i want to update it otherwise for new email address i need to insert new record in registerTempTable and further to the hive table.I am not getting the solution to insert else update using if..that to for nested json data...plz help me

Comment: i want generalized code for upadte and insert from getting the registerTempTable itself..i thougth using primary key as unique identifier it will help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `monotonically increasing id` which gives unique id for each row.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.withColumn("Keys",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

Comment: so at the end you have one more column as "keys" which is unique identifier as per your requirement.

Comment: but each time the new records i will get in registerTempTable it will generate same monotonically generated id's which i have already in my hive table (permanent table)from the previously generated monotonically id's(from 0 to n as per records)

Comment: in this case first you have to add keys then second time you have to find max count of keys. and then used  `spark.sql("select (row_number()+max(keys))  over (order by any column) as kesy, "other columns" from df")`